# How to add a cancel question at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin-android-extensions

When I delete data from RecyclerView and db I want to be able to undo it.  I want to make sure that there is a small question from the bottom of the screen that will disappear over time.  How can i implement this

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Snackbar

```
 Snackbar.make(parentLayout, "Item deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG) 
        .setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    ///perform undo here
            } 
        }) 
        .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light ))
        .show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(getView(), "My Placeholder Text", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackbar.addCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
      //remove your data from database here
      ...  
    }

    @Override
    public void onShown(Snackbar snackbar) {
       ...
    }
  });
```